# Modify WP-Login Page With Javascript?

Tags: wp-login-form

This may be a 'noob' question, but...

It doesn't seem possible to modify the WP-Login page via PHP (eg. add the get_header() code or new DIVs) to match the site theme. That is, without hacking the core, of course. (If there -is- a way to do this, please let me know!) And -yes- I am aware you can create a login template, but you can never get -rid- of WP-Login because it seems necessary for various core login/logout functions. (Again, if this has changed with WP4, please let me know!)

So, I've taken to simply adding the DIVs I want via jQuery(). Nothing extravagant... just a 'header' and 'footer' to match the site theme.

My question is: are there any reasons to -not- do this? ie. security concerns or other problems I haven't considered? I ask because there must be a good reason why this is the -one- place in WP where you can't use a 'template' page and that seems odd to me.

TIA

Comment: I recommend keeping it simple, add the style using CSS! You can provide a simple branded experience without chiding or breaking anything!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can have custom login/logout actions without visitors seeing WP admin enviroment. So I am not answering "modify WP-login page with JS" question, but letting know there is easier solution

You can add this form anywhere to you template, and voila, the login form!

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo site_url('/wp-login.php') ?>" method="post">
<table class="logtable">
<tr>
    <td class="first"><label for="user_login"><?php _e('Username:','your-theme') ?></label></td>
    <td class="second"><input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="first"><label for="user_pass"><?php _e('Password:','your-theme') ?></label></td>
    <td class="second"><input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="remember" colspan="2">
        <label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"> <?php _e('Remember me','your-theme') ?></label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="submit" colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Log in','your-theme') ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo home_url() ?>">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

You want user to log in, but you don't want him to see admin enviroment. So you can "block" him from admin entirely (and redirect him to home page).

```
function blockDashboard() {
    $file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    if (is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator') && $file != 'admin-ajax.php'){
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'blockDashboard' );
```

And log out link? Easy.

```
<p class="logout">
<?php wp_loginout( home_url() ) ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this. However, experienced WP users always somehow find their way to the wp-login.php URL. So I prefer to simply modify wp-login rather than creating new page. (To tighten this up, I have tried disabling wp-login via .htaccess and it breaks WP. Apparently WP needs that page to be visible?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like this:

```
<?php
add_action('login_header', function () {
    wp_dequeue_style('login');
    wp_deregister_style('login');
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html <?php language_attributes();?>>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/head');?>
        <body <?php body_class();?>>
        <!--[if IE]>
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <?php _e('You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.', 'sage');?>
            </div>
        <![endif]-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
            <?php
    do_action('get_header');
    get_template_part('templates/header');
    ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap container w-75" role="document">
            <div class="content row">
                <main class="main">
        <?php
});

add_action('login_footer', function () {
    ?>
        </main><!-- /.main -->
      </div><!-- /.content -->
    </div><!-- /.wrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery("body").addClass("custom-background");
        //jQuery("#login-css").remove();
    </script>
    <?php
    do_action('get_footer');
    get_template_part('templates/footer');
    wp_footer();
    ?>
  </body>
    </html><?php
});
```

You can remove login.css file with uncommenting the script

```
jQuery("#login-css").remove();
```

but after that you'll need to re-style the login box.